# DebugDiag not completing analysis

Tags: .net, cpu-usage, debugdiag

I have been trying to find high cpu usage, for a .NET web application. I used the DebugDiag tool as explained in this article: https://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/performance-issues/troubleshooting-high-cpu-in-an-iis-7x-application-pool

The dump was successfully collected, but when the dump is analyzed using the DebugDiag Analyzer, its running for hours, without completing. How long does it actually takes?

There is no indication when it will complete. The dump file size is around 6.6 GB and the analyzer is run on the same machine where the dump was created.

Answer (score 0):

If the dump is 6.6gb I'd recommend taking it off the machine in question and running it on another machine. A report of 400mb can take 4-5 minutes to run. I don't even want to think on how long a 6.6gb one would take to run.