# DebugDiag Analysis hangs while "Dumping Thread Data"

Tags: iis, analysis, iis-10, debugdiag

I'm trying to run [DebugDiag Analysis (v2.3)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58210) on my Windows 10 laptop using crash-dump files generated from a w3wp.exe process on a Windows Server 2016 box... but the application never passes "Dumping Thread Data" (the progress animation continues, so it's not a GUI hang.)

(I am not allowed to installed DebugDiag on the server, as it is production box and owned by a client. They allowed me to change the registry settings to generate the crash-dump files, which I then copied to my local machine.)

IIS-10 is running an ASP.Net 4.5.2 web application, and the corresponding event log entries on the Server (when the crash-dump files were generated) suggest there is an unhandled stackoverflow (`0xc000000fd`).

I've tried all of the crash-dump files, which are approximately 50Mb in size - but I end up just quitting DebugDiag because it never passes "Dumping Thread Data".

According to the only answer on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43649851/debugdiag-not-completing-analysis) a file of 400Mb "can take 4-5 minutes to run"... however, I've left my (quite powerful) laptop running the analysis of 50Mb for well over 30 minutes with no progress.

I've also seen that an [internet connection is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56782704/debugdiag-analysis-is-taking-too-long-to-generate-the-report) - and I can confirm that I have a quick connection, so that shouldn't be the issue.

If required I can place a file somewhere to download, but don't want to do that unless it's really necessary.

I'm doubtful anybody will be able to help, but I'm struggling to see how to fix this

Comment: DebugDiag is just a simple free tool, which is known to have many issues when analyzing dumps. So in your case, you should give it up and learn how to analyze the dumps with other tools (like WinDbg).

Comment: Thanks @Lex, I wrongly assumed it was more robust... I'll have a look at WinDbg

Comment: I found DebugDiag 2.1 quite reliabe and a good tool for getting a first impression. Your Internet connection sometimes doesn't matter. If the server is slow, that's it.

Comment: @Thomas - thanks for the response, but the server speed has nothing to do with it. These are crash dump files that have been brought to my local machine for processing, I'm not doing remote IIS analysis

Comment: @freefaller: I meant Microsoft symbol servers could be slow. Not your IIS server.

Comment: @Thomas - Apologies, I understand now